# An implication involving filters

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $z$ be a filter on a set $U$ and $I$, $J$ be sets of filters on $U$.

Is the following implication always true?

$$(\forall K \in z\, \exists x \in I \cup J : x \supseteq \mathop\uparrow\!\! K) \Rightarrow (\forall K
\in z\, \exists x \in I : x \supseteq \mathop\uparrow\!\! K) \vee (\forall K \in z\, \exists x \in J : x
\supseteq \mathop\uparrow\!\! K)$$

where $\mathop\uparrow\!\! K$ is the principal filter generated by a set $K$.

If it is not always true (counterexample?), which additional conditions may we require to make it provable?

I need this for my own research.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense. If $x\in I\cup J$, then $x$ is a filter. If $K\in z$, then $K$ is a subset of $U$. Possibly $K\in x$, but not $K\subseteq x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I've corrected my question

Comment: Would a few parentheses be too much to ask for? I can't figure out what that huge statement is saying.

Comment: @dfeuer: I've added more parentheses

Comment: I have removed your link as it adds nothing to the post and comes across as self-promotion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is true. It’s equivalent to the simpler assertion

$$\forall K\in z\,\exists x\in I\cup J(K\in x)\to\Big(\forall K\in z\,\exists x\in I(K\in x)\lor\forall K\in z\,\exists x\in J(K\in x)\Big)\;.$$

Suppose that it fails for some $z,I$, and $J$. Then there are $K_I,K_J\in z$, $x_I\in I$, and $x_J\in J$ such that $K_I\in x_I$, $K_J\in x_J$, $\forall x\in I(K_J\notin x)$, and $\forall x\in J(K_I\notin x)$. Let $K=K_I\cap K_J\in z$; there is an $x\in I\cup J$ such that $K\in x$. Without loss of generality $x\in I$. But then $K_J\supseteq K\in x\in I$, so $K_J\in x\in I$, contradicting the choice of $K_J$.

Comment: What is $(K\in x)$?

Comment: @porton: I don’t understand the question. It means what it always means: $K$ is an element of (the filter) $x$.

Comment: Oh, I have understood

Comment: It seems there is an error in your proof: "$x_I\in I$, and $x_J\in J$" should be instead "$x_I\in I$, or $x_J\in J$"

Comment: @porton: If you mean the sentence that starts *Then there are*, it is correct as it stands. The negation of a disjunction is a conjunction.